# C# windows form printing two pages in single button click

Tags: c#, winforms

i'm creating a windows form application in C#. I want to create a printing functionality/ print receipt where two pages will print one named "Customer Copy" and another "Office copy".The printing receipt takes data from a data grid view controlls.

How can i do that.
Plz help me with this.

Comment: Show your printing code.. there are lot of examples on the internet that you can use to print the document. Which one you are using?

Answer (score 0):

```
        //create document - recipt
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            if (i == 0)
            {
                //title = Customer Copy
            }
            else
            {
                //title = Office copy
            }
            //print document
        }
```

Comment: A better design would be to encapsulate this in a function. What you've got here is more than a little silly.